# I don't understand part of a proof for Fundamental Theorem of Calculus 2

Tags: calculus

I am currently going over [MIT lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pd2xP5zDsRw) and I cannot understand the proof for FTC2.
The professor writes: $\Delta G = \Delta x\ f(x)$

and

$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta G}{\Delta x} = f(x)$

Where $G$ is the area under the curve (as far as I understand).
The idea is - if we increase $x$ by a bit - what is the change in the area (as I understand...). We multiply the base (change in $x$ which is $\Delta x$) of a rectangle under the curve by the height - the function value.

What unclear to me is: why we take limit as $\Delta x \to 0$?

I feel like it should be:

$\lim_{\Delta x \to 1}\frac{\Delta G}{\Delta x} = f(x)$

Because  $\Delta G = f(x)$ in case $\Delta x = 1$. If it is less than 1 - then we won't get $f(x)$.

Where am I wrong???

Comment: When you take a derivative, you want to find the slope of the line connecting two points as their separation becomes very small, i.e., as it approaches $0$. They're just applying the definition of the derivative here.